# jQuery print function, how to use iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, printing, html-table

I am making a print function for printing a list within a div. When the print button is clicked, the data in the inputs for the list is placed a new input that will be printed. I have been asked to remove blank inputs and have the filled ones appear together. I have been told to use a while iteration, but I don't even know how to go about doing that.

My inputs that send the data to be printed are the `printArea_#` and placed in the `printLoad_#`

I was given this code, but don't know how to use it...

```
$('#mydiv').children('input [type=text]').each(function () {
    alert(this.value); // "this" is the current element in the loop
});​
```

This is my working print function, it places the data into the new input for printing, but still displays the empty data as well, ( I am sure there is a much cleaner way to do this too.)

```
function print_list() {
    $('input[id=printLoad_1]').val($('input[class=printArea_1]').val());
    $('input[id=printLoad_2]').val($('input[class=printArea_2]').val());
    $('input[id=printLoad_3]').val($('input[class=printArea_3]').val());
    $('input[id=printLoad_4]').val($('input[class=printArea_4]').val());
    $('input[id=printLoad_5]').val($('input[class=printArea_5]').val());
    $('input[id=printLoad_6]').val($('input[class=printArea_6]').val());
    $('input[id=printLoad_7]').val($('input[class=printArea_7]').val());
    $('input[id=printLoad_8]').val($('input[class=printArea_8]').val());
    $('input[id=printLoad_9]').val($('input[class=printArea_9]').val());
        $(".printing_list").printElement(
            {
            overrideElementCSS:[
                '/css/print_fixer.css',
                { href:'/css/print_fixer.css',media:'print'}],
            //leaveOpen:true,
            //printMode:'popup',

            });
}
```

I want to hide unfilled table rows until data has been placed into one of the inputs.
Here is an example of one of my table rows.

```
       <tr id="num_1">
                <td><input id="printLoad_1" type="text" style="width:700px;" /></td>
       </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
var inputLength = $("input[id^='printLoad']").length;

for (var i = 1; i <= inputLength; i++) {
    $('input[id=printLoad_' + i + ']').val($('input[class=printArea_' + i + ']').val());
    if ($('input[id=printLoad_1]').val($('input[class=printArea_1]').val() == "") {
        $("#num_" + i).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an error on the If line, I have no idea what it is either lol.

Comment: @user2089255 Loops are definitely something to familiarize yourself with, glad I could help. If it answers your question, please mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the help. This worked well for my needs!